# Error in AWS CDK V2 construct for AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have written code to create a repo and a few properties.  Even though I am passing `reponame` as a string 'testing' as part of an interface, my code is going through the else condition and creating the `reponame` as undefined+date.

2nd issue: Can you also help me to find the issue for the principal in the permission policy?  I am receiving an error saying `props.accountIds.map` is wrong: I am passing an array to accountIds.

```js
    import * as ecr from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecr';
    import { Duration, RemovalPolicy, Stack } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
    import { Repository, RepositoryEncryption, TagMutability } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecr';
    import {AWSAccountDetails} from '../lib/utils/definition';  
    import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
    
    export class ecrStack extends cdk.Stack {
        constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props: any ){
        super(scope, id);
        const repository = this.createEcr(props);
        this.createAdditionalProperty(repository,props);
      }
    //Method to check and create the AWS ECR REPO
    private  createEcr( props: AWSAccountDetails): any {
      
    let imageTagMutability : ecr.TagMutability = ecr.TagMutability.IMMUTABLE;
    let imageScanOnPush : Boolean =true;
    let encryption : ecr.RepositoryEncryption =ecr.RepositoryEncryption.KMS;
    
    if ( props.imageTagMutability  in ecr.TagMutability ) {
      imageTagMutability =props.imageTagMutability;
    }
    
    if (typeof props.imageScanOnPush ! == 'boolean'){
      imageScanOnPush =props.imageScanOnPush;
    }
    
    if (typeof props.encryption ! == 'undefined'){
      encryption =props.encryption;
    }
    if (!props.repositoryName) {
      throw  Error('No repository name provided');
    }
    
      let repository = ecr.Repository.fromRepositoryName(this, 'ecrRepo', props.repositoryName);
    if (!repository.repositoryArn) {
      // Repository does not exist, create a new one with the original name
      repository=new ecr.Repository(this, props.repositoryName, {
        repositoryName: props.repositoryName,
        imageTagMutability: props.imageTagMutability,
        encryption: RepositoryEncryption.KMS,
        imageScanOnPush: props.imageScanOnPush,
        removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
      });
    } else {
      const modifiedRepositoryName = `${props.repositoryName}-${Date.now()}`;
      repository= new ecr.Repository(this, modifiedRepositoryName, {
        repositoryName: modifiedRepositoryName,
        imageTagMutability: props.imageTagMutability,
        encryption: RepositoryEncryption.KMS,
        imageScanOnPush: props.imageScanOnPush,
        removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
      });
    }return repository;
    }
    //Method to add the lifecycle policy,Tags and create aws account permissions.
    private createAdditionalProperty(repository: any, props:AWSAccountDetails) {
    
      let AgeOfImage :number =180;
    
      if (typeof props.ImageAge ! == 'undefined'){
    
          repository.addLifecycleRule({
            rulePriority: 1,
            maxImageAge:Duration.days(AgeOfImage)
          });
        } else {
          repository.addLifecycleRule({
            rulePriority: 1,
            maxImageAge:Duration.days(props.ImageAge) 
          });
    }
        //Tags 
        const Tags:{[key:string]:string}={
            Name: props.repositoryName,
        }
        //Permission to external aws account to grant permission for ECR pull and push
         //  const policy = new iam.PolicyDocument();
            //policy.addStatements(new iam.PolicyStatement({
             // actions: ['ecr:*'],
              //actions: ['ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability', 'ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer', 'ecr:BatchGetImage', 'ecr:PutImage']
           //   resources: [repository.repositoryArn],
           //   principals: props.accountIds.map(id => new iam.AccountPrincipal(id))
           // }));
    }
      addLifecycleRule(arg0: { rulePriority: number; maxImageAge: Duration; }) {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
      }
    }
```

The interface file:

```js
    import * as ecr from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecr';
    import { ecrStack } from '../ecrstack-stack';
    
    export interface AWSAccountDetails  {
        ImageCount: any;
        readonly repositoryName :'abcd';   /* Repo Name */ 
        readonly ImageAge:110; //Number of days before image is deleted.i.e 90.  need to change to imageAge
        readonly imageTagMutability : ecr.TagMutability.IMMUTABLE;  /* If the Repo should  enable Tag Immutability  or not; Default setting is Enabled */
        readonly imageScanOnPush : true; /* If the Repo should enable ScanonPush or not ; Default setting is Enabled */
        readonly encryption : 'KMS'; /* If the Repo should KMS or not  ; Default setting is Enabled for AWS managed KMS Key*/
        readonly accountIds : string //Account number to grant access to pull and push.
        readonly encruptionproperty: 'KMS';
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to pass the props as object and then export to the main stack. This solved the issue.